# How to make Wordpress plugin pages look like the standard admin pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to writing WP plugins. My plugin code is ready so I'm working on the admin pages.

Is there an easy way to create similar tables and forms as the rest of WP admin pages or one is left to reverse engineer those interfaces or make his own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an entire [documentation section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) about it. Also, there's a [plugin to help you style your plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style), that shows all the styling used by the admin interface.